# Browse button of filefield missing

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a `filefield` in my extjs page. The upload functionality is working fine, alright.
The filefield is placed in a widget window. When the window is closed and reopened the filefield doesn't create properly. The **browse button** is missing in it. This happens only when I close the window without uploading anything at all.
The below is the code for the same:

```
var stockAuditUploadFile = Ext.widget('window', {
  title: 'Upload the Stock Audit file',
  closeAction: 'hide',
  width: 500,
  autoHeight: true,
  layout: 'fit',
  resizable: false,
  modal: true,
  items: [{
          xtype: 'filefield',
          id: 'filedata',
          emptyText: 'Select a document to upload...',
          fieldLabel: 'File',
          waitMsg: 'Please wait...',
          buttonText: 'Browse',
          validator: function (v) {
              if (!/\.xls$/.test(v)) {
                  return 'Only Excel files allowed';
              }
              return true;
          }
      }],
  buttons: [{
          text: 'Upload',
          handler: function () {
              //callUpload();
              if (myuploadform.getForm().isValid()) {
                  //alert('in456side');
                  form_action = 1;
                  myuploadform.getForm().submit({
                      url: 'submission/stockupload.jsp',
                      success: function (result, action) {
                      }
                  });
              }
              Ext.Msg.alert('File Uploaded Successfully');
              stockAuditUploadFile.destroy();
          }
      }]
});

stockAuditUploadFile.show();
```

When the widget window opens for the first time, everything works fine including the validation for excel file uploading but on close and reopen the browse button is missing.

Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: which version of ExtJs you are using? if possible create a fiddle and link here...

Comment: @newmount The extjs version that I use is 4.2 and the [fiddle is here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dd5). The fiddle works fine but the same code doesn't work in my web page.

Comment: try replacing 'autoWidth: 500' of the window config to 'width' and check..

Comment: That was a typo here, that doesn't change anything on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the above issue.
The `closeAction: 'hide'` was the problem. On hide, things in `Extjs` go wild, haven't understood that yet but on changing the above to `closeAction: 'destroy'` the `filefield` works fine.
Though the `hide` was working in fiddle, it didn't work good for me in my project. So, I believe it is better to use the below even though the hide-closeAction may work good for others.

`closeAction:'destroy'` brings the browse button alright.